# Tagging C++ class instances with metadata

Tags: c++, templates, factory-pattern

I have a C++ factory function which will be used to instantiate certain concrete classes which derive from some abstract class.

From a code operation standpoint, the actual English names of these concrete classes aren't important. Say they're different types of "Event", derived from an "AbstractEvent" class. For the purpose of code function, the actual names of the derived classes don't matter, as they'll all have some kind of unique numerical ID generated at instantiation which will be how other modules will refer to them, which will only work with references to the abstract type, not any particular concrete class.

From a code maintenance perspective, though, it would be helpful for the coder to know whether say, a certain class or method accepted a "FooEvent" templated to work with an int, or a "BarEvent" templated to work with a float, so there's some human-readable term for what the user is working with when using the API.

Is there a "canonical" way to accomplish this? It would be preferable if  the solution didn't generate any run-time overhead.

Comment: That's what comments are for.  You can put together a standardized comment section that can be used for your classes.

Comment: You can use `SFINAE` to enable/disable sections of the API based off the type of event. May not be the most readable, but it wouldn't compile if they did it wrong.

Comment: please post a minimal complete program that demonstrates the way you think it could work. then we can tell you if there's a better way.

Comment: @Richard Hodges Okay, I'll see what I can do. What I was hoping for is that say you have some other user-created class that "accepts" events, and you want to write some bit of code that dispatches function pointers depending on what's received. 

It would be nice if the user could simply work with English terms that mapped to the numerical designations to express the intended function, but didn't actually have to be stored in program memory, or dealt with at runtime.

Comment: @Bitrex do you mean that you simply want to print the name of the class you have created, say in a log?

Comment: @RichardHodges More like, I have some user-created class Class1 I want to template somehow to process two kinds of events, a "FooTypeEvent" and a "BarTypeEvent." So I use the factory function to create those class instances, and they end up with some kind of internal ID number and a location in memory, but they also can be thought of by the programmer as being a "FooTypeEvent" etc.

Then when that event turns up in Class1's queue, Class1 says "Ah, that internal ID number mean's it's a 'FooTypeEvent' and I should accept that, because I was declared to accept that type of event."

Comment: @RichardHodges but I want this to be transparent to the user, so they don't have to work with numerical IDs, which might not even be the same between program runs. So if there's work that needs to be done on receipt of such an event, the user might just be able to write something like `if (Event == FOO_TYPE_EVENT)` instead of working with the internal representation.

Comment: hmm... thinking...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how about a constexpr string identifier:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <memory>

struct EventBase
{
    virtual const std::string& type() const = 0;
    virtual ~EventBase() = default;
};

template<const char* type_name>
struct EventModel : EventBase
{

    const std::string& type() const override {
        static const std::string _ { type_name };
        return _;
    }
};

constexpr char hello[] = "hello";
constexpr char world[] = "world";

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    auto p1 = std::make_unique<EventModel<hello>>();
    auto p2 = std::make_unique<EventModel<world>>();

    std::cout << p1->type() << std::endl;
    std::cout << p2->type() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

now you have a number of options for selecting message types:

```
bool is_hello_slow(const EventBase& e)
{
    return e.type() == hello;
}

bool is_hello_medium(const EventBase* pe)
{
    return dynamic_cast<const EventModel<hello>*>(pe);
}

template<class Event>
bool is_hello_compile_time(const Event&) {
    return std::is_base_of<EventModel<hello>, Event>();
}
```

Comment: Yes! This is exactly what I had in mind - being able to template specific events with English designations.